# specify regex in spacy when dates can come in as 04-14-2021 and 04-2022 and 4-2021

Tags: python, regex, date, spacy

How to specify regex in spacy when dates can come in as 04-14-2021 and 04-2022 and 4-2021.

For hyphen, I am using this regex:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens.doc import Doc
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)  
doc: Doc = nlp("4-15-2024 02-26 02 6-2021 05-2021")

pattern_9 = [{'TEXT':{'REGEX':r'^\d{1,2}$'}}, {'TEXT':{'REGEX':r'^-$'}}, {'TEXT':{'REGEX':r'^\d{2,4}$'}}] #e.g. Jun-2021

matcher.add('DATE_PATTERN_9', [pattern_9])

matches = matcher(doc)
print(f"matches = {matches}")

for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print( span.text)
```

Document:

```py
Doc = nlp("4-15-2024 02-26 02 6-2021 05-2021")
```

It split `4-15-2024` into `4-15` & `15-2024` but I want only `mm-yy` or `mm-yyyy` as output.

Right now, I am getting below output for the above pattern:

```
4-15
15-2024
02-26
6-2021
05-2021
```

Comment: What model are you loading? Please add the full code to repro the issue. I get expected matches with `nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")`

Comment: Just re-tested with `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`, and got the expected results. You must be using custom tokenization then.

Comment: I have added full code here which i am using here. I am also using nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') & getting the attached output but i want only mm-yy dont want to split dd-mm-yyyy into 2 portion

Comment: Sorry, I cannot repro.

Comment: You are getting which output using this code

Comment: The one at the end of the question.

Comment: yes i am also getting same, but if you see 4-15-2024 is also coming as 4-15 & 15-2024 which is not correct so i dont want to consider dd-mm-yyyy only mm-yyyy will come up as output

Comment: Ok, you should be more precise with what you need to get in the end. Do you only want to see `4-15-2024`?

Comment: Also, `Jun-2021` is not the pattern that can be matched with your regexps. The pattern only matches `11-11`, `1-11`, `11-111`, `11-1111` like strings

Comment: i want only below pattern to be come
02-26
6-2021
05-2021

only mm-yyyy, not dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Yes it wont consider Jun-2021 for that different pattern required

Comment: Aha, now it is clear what you want.

Comment: Can you help me in this for getting output of 02-26, 6-2021 05-2021 & Jun-2021

Comment: Sorry, spacy does not allow checking for context when using matcher. It is a not a pure regex issue. You probably can do something with textacy, but I have not used it. You may achieve what you want with pure regex though.